# Explicación de código - Java

Tags: java, poo, object

Poseeo la siguiente duda

Para que sirve, y exactamente que hacen las siguientes lineas:

-Profesor p;

-p= new Profesor(ht, ch, cod, nombres, cedula);

Dentro de este programa?

```
    cod=txtCod.getText();
    nombres= txtNombres.getText();
    cedula= txtDNI.getText();

    double ht, ch;
    Profesor p;

    ht=Double.parseDouble(txtHt.getText());
    ch=Double.parseDouble(txtCh.getText());

    p= new Profesor(ht, ch, cod, nombres, cedula);

    lblCostoP.setText("Sr. "+nombres+" cobrar: "+String.valueOf(p.getCostoPagar()));
}
```

El profesor nos a subido este programa, pero dentro contiene ciertas intrucciones que desconosco su función, soy nuevo en esto, y ojala me puedan ayudar.
El programa es de manera visual y trabaja con herencias, este codigo esta dentro del botón del frontal, y lo que hace basicamente es calcular el sueldo de un docente de acuerdo a las horas que este aya trabajado. Si es necesario el codigo de todas las clases, por favor, me lo hacen saber, gracias de ante mano.

Comment: La primera define una variable de tipo Profesor. La segunda instacia un objeto de ese tipo llamando a un constructor que recibe varios parametros de entrada (estudia la clase Profesor). Esto es lo más basico en la programación orientada a objetos, no creo que no haya sido explicado por tu profesor :)

Comment: En realidad no, por que nunca termino el codigo, asi que nos subio estó a una plataforma para que lo miraramos...

Comment: En el comentario de @Pikoh, te da una breve respuesta sobre lo que hace el código y de dicha explicación podrías partir, deberías leer sobre Programación Orientada a Objetos para que tengas un mejor entendimiento.